# Grails, Vaadin, and Spring Security Plugin together

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, vaadin

I've got grails working with vaadin and spring security core plugins, but cannot combine the three. If I go to a page where I use @Secured, it works as it is supposed to. But if I put @Secured in my vaadin application class, it doesn't do anything. What I am looking to do is to secure the entire vaadin application, and then secure some things within that application for higher authority roles. What am I doing wrong here? If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this post](http://sebastien-arbogast.com/2011/02/23/grails-vaadin-and-spring-security-core/) - he puts the methods to be secured into a Grails service class, where the annotations work, and is calling the service methods from the vaadin application.

(Be aware that relying on dependency injection is not recommended in vaadin apps, see getBean(String beanName) getBean(Class beanType) in the [plugin docs](http://grails.org/plugin/vaadin)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the URL-mappings in Config.groovy?

The @Secured-annotation is to be used in grails controller classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Grails services into your Vaadin application.
Using Vaadin plugin, declare your service in your UI or any Vaadin Component, for instance:

```
import com.vaadin.grails.Grails
import com.company.app.SecurityService

class <YourComponent> extends CustomComponent implements View {

def securityService = Grails.get(SecurityService)
...
<use securityService in your component's methods>

}
```

In your grails service named "securityService", wire the springSecurityService, and use annotations or anything provided by spring-security grails plugin. Moreover, thanks to Grails goodness, services are already transactionnal.

```
@Transactional
class SecurityService {

    def springSecurityService

    def signOut() {
        SCH.context.authentication = null
    }

    boolean isSignedIn() {
        return springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()
    }

    User getCurrentUser() {
        return springSecurityService.currentUser
    }
```

... Or whatever security concerns.